# How to use the map() function from the tidyverse package correctly in adding layers of matrix calculations?

Tags: r, matrix, purrr

I am new to the `map()` function and have hit a stumbling block. In the code below denoted as "working code", it works fine. Working code expands the elements in the `matList` list into a little group of matrices for each series ("mat_One", etc.) embedded in `matList` and calculates the "Inflows" column of each matrix as the product of the respective series vector values embedded in the `allocate` list and the value in the `flexVector` vector.

In the below "Failed code" I am trying to insert into the "Due" columns of the rendered matrices the products of the `balVector` (no series designation) and the `ratesVector` (for the applicable series) with the line of code `Due = balVector * alc * rates[[names(allocate)]][[.y]]`, but I get an error message.

What am I doing wrong with my use of the `map()` function?

More generally, I need to know how to perform calculations by moving through various matrices and vectors using `map()` and `reduce()`. I have more calculation columns to add, some of which don't move in parallel through 2 vectors the way that `map2()` does.

In the image below I show what the output of running `createBucketMap()` should look like.

[image]

**Working code:**

```
library(tidyverse)

seriesVector <- function() {c("mat_One", "mat_Two")}
matList <- list(mat_One = c("Boy", "Cat"),mat_Two = c("Boy", "Bat"))
allocate <- list(mat_One = c(0.6,0.5,0.4),mat_Two = c(0.4,0.5,0.6))
flowVector <- c(6,5,4)
balVector <- c(1000,900,800)
rates <- list(mat_One = 0.10,mat_Two = 0.20)

createBucketMap <- function(){
  map(allocate, \(alc) alc*flowVector) |>
  map2(matList, \(alc, matL) expand.grid(
    V1 = matL, 
    Inflow = alc,
    Due = 0,
    Cover_due = 0,
    Outflow = 0)
     ) |>
  map(\(dfs) group_split(dfs, V1, .keep = FALSE) |>
        map(as.matrix))  |>
  map2(matList, ~set_names(.x, .y))
}
createBucketMap()
```

**Failed code:**

```
library(tidyverse)
createBucketMap <- function() {
  map(allocate, \(alc) alc * flowVector) |>
    map2(matList, \(alc, matL) expand.grid(
      V1 = matL,
      Inflow = alc,
      Due = balVector * alc * rates[[names(allocate)]][[.y]],
      Cover_due = 0,
      Outflow = 0)
    ) |>
    map(\(dfs) group_split(dfs, V1, .keep = FALSE) |> 
          map(as.matrix)) |>
    map2(matList, ~ set_names(.x, .y))
}
createBucketMap()
```

**Edit OP:** add code from the accepted answer but without using an intermediate dataframe, running all calculations on only a matrix:

```
createBucketMap <- function() {
  imap(matList, \(matL, matL_name) {
    map(matL, \(x) {
      alc <- allocate[[matL_name]]
      rate <- rates[[matL_name]]
      matrix(
        c(flowVector * alc, balVector * alc * rate, rep(0, length(flowVector)), rep(0, length(flowVector))),
        ncol = 4,
        dimnames = list(NULL, c("Inflow", "Due", "Cover_due", "Outflow"))
      )
    }) |>
      set_names(matL)
  })
}
createBucketMap()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit unsure about your final result but IMHO you could simplify your code considerably. In the code below I first loop over your `matList` which already reflects the nested structure of your desired final list. To this end I use `imap` which loops over both the list and the list names. For each list element I use another `map` to loop over the inner elements and to create the matrices:

```r
library(tidyverse)

createBucketMap <- function() {
  imap(matList, \(matL, matL_name) {
    map(matL, \(x) {
      alc <- allocate[[matL_name]]
      rate <- rates[[matL_name]]
      data.frame(
        Inflow = flowVector * alc,
        Due = balVector * alc * rate,
        Cover_due = 0,
        Outflow = 0
      ) |>
        as.matrix()
    }) |>
      set_names(matL)
  })
}

createBucketMap()
#> $mat_One
#> $mat_One$Boy
#>      Inflow Due Cover_due Outflow
#> [1,]    3.6  60         0       0
#> [2,]    2.5  45         0       0
#> [3,]    1.6  32         0       0
#> 
#> $mat_One$Cat
#>      Inflow Due Cover_due Outflow
#> [1,]    3.6  60         0       0
#> [2,]    2.5  45         0       0
#> [3,]    1.6  32         0       0
#> 
#> 
#> $mat_Two
#> $mat_Two$Boy
#>      Inflow Due Cover_due Outflow
#> [1,]    2.4  80         0       0
#> [2,]    2.5  90         0       0
#> [3,]    2.4  96         0       0
#> 
#> $mat_Two$Bat
#>      Inflow Due Cover_due Outflow
#> [1,]    2.4  80         0       0
#> [2,]    2.5  90         0       0
#> [3,]    2.4  96         0       0
```

Comment: I've been avoiding using data frames, opting for matrices directly, in order to keep the speed up because there are many long calculations to come. Do you think your step of first creating a data frame (`data.frame(...)`) and then converting to matrix (`as.matrix()`) will be slower than directly working with only matrices rather than intervening dataframes?

Comment: Using a data.frame is a bit more convenient. But creating the matrix directly is definitely faster.

Comment: As I look at the code you posted it is also quite understandable. Thank you for this.

Comment: Hi, I edited the OP to include your solution but without using an intermediate dataframe, instead only using matrix. Please let me know if you see anything goofy in what I did. The results are the same as running your code.